# iMac as a Security cam

Tags: security, webcam

I wonder if I can use Automator to build a security device out of my iMac's camera with the following features:

1. The camera would be continuously recording in a pre-defined schedule
2. It would save the video files locally, no need to stream over the internet
3. In order to keep the space used controlled, I'd limit the video recordings to 2 days, 3 days, or X amount of Megabytes
4. once the limit is reached, old files would be deleted to keep the disk uses space the same

Most of the apps on the net will stream video, I guess. Maybe using Photo Booth and automation that could be done.